# Making sure that data is received and processed

Tags: php, http

I don’t know much PHP and I want to see how/if the following algorithm can be implemented in PHP:

I am sending a string to a PHP script via HTTP GET. When the script receives the data, I PROCESS it and write the result to a txt file. The file already exists. I only update some lines. My problem is: what happens if the server fails while my data is processed? How can I minimize the damage in case of server/script failure?

The processing of data may take up to one second. So I think it is a high risk that the server will breakdown during it. Therefore, I am thinking in breaking it in two parts:

1. One script (let’s call it RECEIVER) that receives the data from HTTP GET and store it to a file (called Jobs.txt). It should finish really fast as it has to write only 20-50 chars.
2. A second script (let’s call it PROCESSOR) that checks this file every 2-3 seconds to see if new entries were added. If it finds new entries, it processes the data, save it and finally deletes the entry from the Jobs file. If the server fails, on resume, maybe I can start my PROCESSOR and start the work from where it was interrupted.

How it sounds?

Problems: What happens if two users are sending GET commands at the same time to the RECEIVER? It will be a conflict on who will write to the file. Also, the PROCESSOR may conflict over that file as it also wants to write to it. How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't you think you have a design flaw there? You're betting everything on "processor" and that the server won't die during the phase where the data is being written. Your server can "die" while only a portion of data was written (I quoted die because I assumed that there can be any error that prevents the server / OS from executing given command). Also, is this for a project of yours or is it an actual implementation of something? As you can see, what you need conforms to the ACID standards and you can guess why databases are being used then :)

Comment: Everything can die due to, for example, hardware failure. I never had this kind of problem in practice but yes, I think it can die.

Comment: Databases are systems that are separate to webservers. When they run in transaction modes, the level at which a failure can occur is hardware level or OS level. Big and proven database systems won't just "die" out of the blue by themselves, something has to be seriously wrong with the computer they're being ran at - and yet again, there are mechanisms in place that ensure you can retrieve your data. Sure, a script communicating with the db can die, however if in transaction mode - you won't get half-written data and end up with wingdings in your dataset.

Comment: The data already exists on the server as files. If DB is a better approach then all files need to be transferred in a DB. However, as a reply to your question I have another question: if the script can die while it writes data to disk, can it die also when it write data to DB?  Do you have a more concrete algorithm example of how I can use ACID in my PHP script? Thanks

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 - Well, mine (hosted by InMotion Hosting) did. This is how I discovered that the current script has problems  :)

Comment: @Michael J.V - So, it looks that switching to DB will improve the reliability. But the second problem (the concurrency on writing the Jobs.txt file) still remains. PS: you may want to post as 'Answer' instead of 'Comment' to get points.

Comment: Well, you should migrate all the data to the db and forget about writing anything to the Jobs.txt file. Just use transactions to store the new jobs and that's it. I'd write up what transactions do and how the integrity is preserved, but it's easier if you google that up a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael J.V. suggested, using a DB instead of writing to a file will solve some of the problems: "you won't get half-written data and end up with wingdings in your dataset". ACID standards should be used while programming the script: "as you can see, what you need conforms to the ACID standards".

Answer (score 0):

to send some data to PHP use just URL

```
http://www.mydomain.com/myscript.php?getparam1=something&getparam2=something_else
```

to get it from PHP script (in this example myscript.php)

```
$first_parameter = $_GET['getparam1'];
$second_parameter = $_GET['getparam2'];
// or use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET
```

or

```
$get_array = $_GET;
print_r($get_array);
```

or

```
$get_array = explode('; ', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

to write files to text file use:

```
error: This is XXI century!
```

Consider using database rather then text file.

Comment: Thanks but my problem is this: "What happens if two users are sending GET commands at the same time to the RECEIVER? It will be a conflict on who will write to the file. Also, the PROCESSOR may conflict over that file as it also wants to write to it."